# GRAFANA: Templating to the alert rule name dont work for me

Tags: grafana-templating, grafana-alerts

Hellow, I am trying to do this in GRAFANA:
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/old-alerting/add-notification-template/

I mean, I wanna use templating to form a alert Message.

This is my query:

```
from(bucket: "monees")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop:v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => 
        r._measurement == "metrics" and 
        r.type== "alert" and
        r.id == "0001234"
    )
  |> group(columns: ["_time($__interval)", "id ", "name"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every:60s, fn: count)
```

In my Alert config, I have this:

Name: ${id} alert

And in the message:
The id ${id} of service ${name} send a alert.

However, when I receibe via Teams the message, the title says: "${r.id} alert" insteal of "0001234 alert" and in the message: "The id $ of service $ send a alert." insteal of "The id 0001234  of service name_1 send a alert." that is what I expected... ¿Someone know what is wrong?

A lot of Thanks
Hellow, I am trying to do this in GRAFANA:
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/old-alerting/add-notification-template/

I mean, I wanna use templating to form a alert Message.

This is my query in flux:

```
from(bucket: "monees")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop:v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => 
        r._measurement == "metrics" and 
        r.type== "alert" and
        r.id == "0001234"
    )
  |> group(columns: ["_time($__interval)", "id ", "name"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every:60s, fn: count)
```

In my Alert config, I have this:

Name: ${r.id} alert

And in the message:
The id ${id} of service ${name} send a alert.

However, when I receibe via Teams the message, the title says: "${r.id} alert" insteal of "0001234 alert" and in the message: "The id $ of service $ send a alert." insteal of "The id 0001234  of service name_1 send a alert." that is what I expected... ¿Someone know what is wrong?

A lot of Thanks